# How to render combination of 2 components from 2 different React applications?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have 2 independent React applications on a single page (2 calls to `ReactDOM.render()` on different containers in DOM). I can pass JavaScript values from one into another.

I have a component in Application 1, which I need to render with children defined in Application 2. I tried passing a Render Prop from Application 1 to Application 2:

```js
// Application 1 code
application2.send({
  renderApp1Component: (app2Component) => (
    <App1Component>{app2Component}</App1Component>
  )
});
```

Then calling this Render Prop in Application 2:

```js
// Application 2 code
renderApp1Component(<App2Component />);
```

I'm getting errors when calling `renderApp1Component()`, as it seems Application 2 cannot render `<App1Component>`, as it's defined in context of another React application.

Is there a way to do this somehow? I was thinking maybe there is a way to somehow pre-compile `<App2Component>` in Application 2 to DOM element, so that it doesn't need to be fully compiled in Application 1? Then send that result to Application 1, so that `<App1Component>` would include it like any other HTML element without any compilation needed.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. As you yourself wrote: "it's defined in context of another React application."

Comment: Perhaps with a [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)?